# Cargar un fragmento detrás de un diálogo ANDROID

Tags: android

Mi proyecto se distribuye en varios fragmentos. Al pulsar en el botón del fragmento me sale un diálogo y me gustaría que al pulsar en el botón **ok** del diálogo me cambiara el fragmento que hay detrás a otro distinto, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
  builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do something when click positive button
                    for (int i = 0; i<chekedniveles.length; i++){
                        boolean checked = chekedniveles[i];
                        if (checked) {

                            System.out.println(nivelesList.get(i) + "\n");

                        }
                    }
```

Creo que para actualizar el fragmento tiene que ir dentro del botón **ok** del listener, pero me lanza un error.

Comment: Que cambie el fragmento atras del dialogo pero el dialogo continue arriba?

Comment: Hola marcos y bienvenido! ¿Podrías añadir la parte del código que ya tienes o dónde crees que va... etc? Un saludo.

Comment: @Elenasys me gustaría que el dialogo también desapareciera, he  tratado de insertarlo en el listener del botón de enviar del dialogo, pero me marca un error. Perdonar, soy novato. Gracias.

Comment: @MiquelColl Soy novato, gracias por avisar, he añadido donde creo que puede ir, un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que el padre del dialogo es un fragmento, no puedes cambiar el fragmento desde ese dialogo. `FragmentManager` pertenece a `Activity`. Un fragmento no puede (ni debe) removerse a sí mismo. Pues la actividad es quien conoce y administra todos los fragmentos incluido él mismo.

Supongamos que tu código de manejo del evento del dialogo está en el fragmento. No podrás cambiar el fragmento desde ese código. Necesitarás pedirle a la actividad padre que lo haga. Puedes utilizar una [interfaz](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaz_(Java)) para establecer la comunicación con la actividad padre.

En la plantilla de código que genera Android Studio para cada fragmento se incluye un código de plantilla para esta interfaz. Esta interfaz permite *enviar mensajes* a la actividad padre. Es completamente válido enviar un mensaje de autodestrucción.

Por ejemplo, en el fragmento:

```
public class MiFragmento extends Fragment {
OnDestruir mCallback;

// La actividad padre debe implementar esta interfaz
public interface OnDestruir {
    public void onDestruirFragmento(Fragment miFragmento);
    // Puedes agregar más si necesitas
}
// El resto del código
}
```

En el *Handler* del botón:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // Mucho código por aquí
    Fragment.this.mCallback.onDestruirFragmento(this);
    }
```

Y en la actividad:

```
public static class MiActividad extends Activity implements MiFragmento.OnDestruir{
    // Mucho más código por acá

    // Esta es la implementación de la interfaz.
    public void onDestruir(Fragment quien) {
    /* 
     * Aquí ya puedes acceder a FragmentManager, destruir 'quien'
     * y reemplazarlo por otro, o lo que necesites.
     */
    }
}
```

Debes asegurar que la actividad implemente la interfaz. La [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) de Android Developers en inglés tiene más información al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Nunca he probado hacer eso,pero he logrado comunicar un DialogFragment con una activity de manera muy satisfactoria mediante una interfaz. Puedes probar con esa variante a ver. Saludos

Comment: Hola Gabriel  me podrías decir exactamente  a lo que te refieres, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En base a tu comentario, deseas que al dar clic en el botón cambie el fragmento...

Esto lo puedes realizar mediante una transacción de fragmentos, al cambiar a otro fragmento el diálogo se cierra ya que el fragmento que lo abrió inicialmente dejó de existir.

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do something when click positive button
                    for (int i = 0; i<chekedniveles.length; i++){
                        boolean checked = chekedniveles[i];
                        if (checked) {

                            System.out.println(nivelesList.get(i) + "\n");

                        }
                    }

                  // Crea el nuevo fragmento y la transacción.
                  Fragment nuevoFragmento = new myFragment();
                  FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                  transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nuevoFragmento);
                  transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                  // Commit a la transacción
                  transaction.commit();

                 }
```

Comment: al estar dentro de un fragmento no me deja usar getFragmentManager(), sabes como puedo solucionarlo? Gracias!